How to correctly manage databinding and serialization/deserialization of a BitmapImage?
That's my basic code:
public class MyObject
{
    public decimal MyDeciaml { get; set; }
    public string? MyImageBase64
    {
        get
        {
            if (MyImageBase64 != null)
            {
                byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(MyImageBase64);
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
                {
                    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
                    bitmapImage.EndInit();
                    bitmapImage.Freeze();
                    MyImageBitmap = bitmapImage;
                }
            }

            return MyImageBase64;
        }
        set { }
    }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public BitmapImage? MyImageBitmap { get; set; }
}

which I bind using a ViewModelData class and ObservableCollection<MyObject> myObjects = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>(); against a ListBox:
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Image x:Name="myImage"
                           Source="{Binding MyImageBitmap}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Width="Auto"
                           Height="Auto" />
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDeciaml }" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

It seems to works nice on binding. Now, when I serialize it on json using Newtonsoft.Json's JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), I see this on the json:
"MyImageBitmap": "System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage"

How can I remove it? It seems [JsonIgnore] has no effect?
I want to remove, and just keep MyImageBase64 (on deserialization, convert it to BitmapImage, and get back the image).
Thanks for any tips on this. Maybe a better way is to bind directly the base64 string and do the conversion to BitmapImage on ListBox, if possible?

I suspect your JsonIgnore is from different namespace - Microsoft not Newton. This is why it doesn't "work"

Why would you serialize a bitmap frame at all? Could you not simply keep the file name?

@Clemens to keep data on project file serialized when moving between devices

Use a byte array for the image in the data class.

Newtonsoft.Json uses a base64 converter for byte arrays by default
Image.Source can be bound to a byte array

So change your class to
public class MyObject
{
    public decimal MyDeciaml { get; set; }
    public byte[] MyImage { get; set; }
}

and the Xaml to
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Image x:Name="myImage"
                           Source="{Binding MyImage}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Width="Auto"
                           Height="Auto" />
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDeciaml}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>


This is certainly the better approach. As a note, although simply copied from the question, MyDeciaml  should be MyDecimal, and x:Name="myImage" is useless, as well as Width="Auto" and Height="Auto".

Your code won't work at all. An assignment to the MyImageBase64 property has no effect because the property setter is empty. And the getter would recursively call itself and hence end up in a StackOverflow exception.
You may write it like shown below, where the BitmapImage is only created when the getter of the (read-only) MyImageBitmap property is actually accessed.
public class MyObject
{
    private string myImageBase64;
    private BitmapImage myBitmapImage;

    public string MyImageBase64
    {
        get { return myImageBase64; }
        set
        {
            myImageBase64 = value;
            myBitmapImage = null; // reset
        }
    }

    public BitmapImage MyImageBitmap
    {
        get
        {
            if (myBitmapImage == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(myImageBase64))
            {
                byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(myImageBase64);

                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
                {
                    myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                    myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
                    myBitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    myBitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
                    myBitmapImage.EndInit();
                    myBitmapImage.Freeze();
                }
            }

            return myBitmapImage;
        }
    }
}


Besides that, it is unclear why the JsonIgnore attribute won't work in your case. You may however remove the MyImageBitmap property and create the BitmapImage in a Binding Converter.
The converter implementation could like like this:
public class Base64ToBitmapImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var imageBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(value.ToString());

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
        {
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
            bitmapImage.Freeze();
            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

In XAML, it would typically be declared as resource:
<Window.Resources>
    ...
    <local:Base64ToBitmapImageConverter x:Key="Base64ToBitmapImageConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

And used in a Binding like this:
<Image Source="{Binding MyImageBase64,
                Converter={StaticResource Base64ToBitmapImageConverter}}" .../>


Can you show to me please how to implement an Binding Converter for that specific field? I would say its the best choice.
